# Google App Engine Java: Full Text Search example needed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore with lots of entities. I want to implement a search functionality that will return me results from the the datastore. I understand that I have to use https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/. Can someone please suggest me the best approach to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach suggested in the documentation?

Comment: I am actually looking for a complete example for using search api and the best practices to follow.

Comment: The documentation already contains the complete example of using an API and many recommendations on best practices. Your question needs to be more specific.